# UITableview datasource methods and retrieving json as the datasource

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

I'm using the RestKit library to load json from my REST services, and then mapping the data to an object.

If I apply that retrieved object as the datasource, the tableview datasource methods run before the json is downloaded, which leaves [list count] at 0.

Now, how do I prevent the table from loading or refresh the table when the json is retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Read your JSON into an array and use that as the data source for your table
2.) If your JSON updates, have some function

```
-(void)tableDataDidUpdate
```

that takes in your JSON, throws out the old table data array and replaces it with a new array.

3.) Make sure to call "reloadData"

```
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: yep, I placed [self.tableView reloadData]; in the RestKit delegate for when the data is fully retrieved. However, it's not very attractive when you see the default empty cells suddenly change into large cells with content. I may need to look into a loading screen function!